# Expanding tabs independent of each other in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 tables; when you click the corner of one, all 3 expand. I would like them to expand independently. How can I accomplish this?

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flip").click(function () {
        $(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
table th, table td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
thead tr th {
    background-color: #00745e;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
table tr th img {
    float: right;
}
table td {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.panel {
    display: none;
}
.flip {
}
.toggle {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    background-image: url('../EPL-Static/images/soccer.png');
    height: 20px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-grid  grid_item">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="9">Chelsea vs Manchester United <a href="#" class="toggle flip"></a>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">EPL1</td>
            <td colspan="3">NGN</td>
            <td colspan="3">Tick</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" class="panel">
                <p>expand info</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Box 2 -->
<table class="table-grid  grid_item">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="9">Arsenal vs Tottenham Hospur <a href="#" class="toggle flip"></a>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">EPL2</td>
            <td colspan="3">NGN</td>
            <td colspan="3">Tick</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" class="panel">
                <p>expand info</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- Box 3 -->
<table class="table-grid  grid_item">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="9">Liverpool vs Sunderland United <a href="#" class="toggle flip"></a>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">EPL1</td>
            <td colspan="3">NGN</td>
            <td colspan="3">Tick</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" class="panel">
                <spam>expand info</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Include the code in the question. Your need to provide us with a self-contained, answerable question for your question to be on-topic here.

Comment: okay, apoligies I didn't know that! I thought including the jsfiddle was sufficiant enough. thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find `.panel` in context of current table. So you need to find the parent table first:

```
$(".flip").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("table").find(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vqm0aL9q/